Scroll to anchor (a href=#) does not directs to given anchor
I have problem with scrolling to anchor (a href="#"). On a given page on right site is a list of content. If You press Zakola Nidy z wieżą widokową for example it stops too soon. You have to click it even 3 times to go to the right position.
I think it has something to do with lazy loaded images, but my code is all native - no js there:
<div data-src="https://static.polskieszlaki.pl/zdjecia/turystyka/2024-03/wislica-171.jpg"
     class="zdjecie cursor-pointer mb-1 d-block" title="Wiślica"
     data-thumb="https://static.polskieszlaki.pl/zdjecia/turystyka/2024-03/100_100/wislica-171.jpg">
    <div class="zdjecie-zaslepka ratio ratio-16x9">
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width: 1400px)"
                    srcset="https://static.polskieszlaki.pl/zdjecia/turystyka/2024-03/960_540/wislica-171.jpg">
            <source media="(min-width: 990px)"
                    srcset="https://static.polskieszlaki.pl/zdjecia/turystyka/2024-03/825_464/wislica-171.jpg">
            <source media="(min-width: 768px)"
                    srcset="https://static.polskieszlaki.pl/zdjecia/turystyka/2024-03/696_392/wislica-171.jpg">
            <source media="(min-width: 1px)"
                    srcset="https://static.polskieszlaki.pl/zdjecia/turystyka/2024-03/516_290/wislica-171.jpg">
            <img decoding="async" loading="lazy"
                 src="https://static.polskieszlaki.pl/zdjecia/turystyka/2024-03/516_290/wislica-171.jpg" alt="Wiślica"
                 class="img-fluid rounded">
        </picture>
    </div>
    <figcaption class="figure-caption p-2 border-bottom rounded-bottom bg-light">Wiślica</figcaption>
</div>

Edit: Even If I remove  decoding="async" loading="lazy" it still acts the same.

"but my code is all native - no js there" - and what's that got to do with anything? The images are getting lazy-loaded, because you put loading="lazy" onto them. JavaScript needs to be active for that to work, but it doesn't require any additional custom coding.

Yes, looks like it's connected with lazy loading of images. Your page has different heights on initial load and after scrolling to the bottom. Have you set width/height attributes for all images?

If I turn off javascript in console images are still loaded. How can I set correct sizes if I have picture with source variants. I do not know which browser will choose

It is not "loading=lazy" attribute. Even if I remove it it acts the same.

works good for me

What browser do You use? I'm testing which element is responsible for that, maybe You refreshed one with striped code

"If I turn off javascript in console images are still loaded." - of course they are. But they won't be loaded "lazy" any more then - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#loading, "Note: Loading is only deferred when JavaScript is enabled. This is an anti-tracking measure, because if a user agent supported lazy loading when scripting is disabled, it would still be possible for a site to track a user's approximate scroll position throughout a session"

"But they won't be loaded "lazy" any more then". So it is not lazy images that causes problem, because even with JS turned off problem is still there. It must be "picture" tag. I don't what to use srcset because browser is not striced with images sizes, always pics too big.

as said above, the height of your elements is chosen when such elements are shown in the viewport and not before. So for example even doing window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); expected to scroll to the bottom of the page, won't actually work as that with the first attempt. You may just force the scroll to bottom and go back to top. But yet it's strange that if you removed the lazy loading it still didn't work. Maybe the class fluid-img giving height auto?

Can you include a [mre]? A lot of the back and forth discussion in the comments could be avoided with a snippet showing the problem.

I know what causes the problem! it is content-visibility: auto on .zdjecie element. If not shown it's height is set to 0. Now I am reading about contain-intrinsic-size. I don't know these attributes.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

Problem was content-visibility: auto on image container. It does not calculate proper height.
